# most recent entry made in table bases on one year interval mysql

Tags: mysql

Using the following sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb8e3/5) How would I find the most recent payment made between the months of `2012-04-1` and `2012-03-31` using the case statement as in the previous queries
I tried this:

```
max(case when py.pay_date >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(2012, '-04-01'),'%Y-%m-%d') and py.pay_date <=  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(2012, '-03-31'), '%Y-%m-%d') + interval 1 year  then py.amount end) CURRENT_PAY
```

However the answer I am getting is incorrect, where the actual answer should be:`(12,   '2012-12-12',    20,        1)`

Please Provide me with some assistance, thank you.

Comment: No the date I have Is correct

Comment: Isn't it  >=March 31 and <= April 1?

Comment: I had missed the + INTERVAL 1 YEAR...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a `CASE` inside your `MAX()` aggregate, that condition belongs in the `WHERE` clause.  This joins against a subquery which pulls the most recent payment per `person_id` by joining on `MAX(pay_date), person_id`.

```
SELECT payment.* 
FROM 
  payment
  JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(pay_date) AS pay_date, person_id 
    FROM payment 
    WHERE pay_date BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND DATE_ADD('2012-03-31', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    GROUP BY person_id
  ) maxp ON payment.person_id = maxp.person_id AND payment.pay_date = maxp.pay_date
```

Here is [an updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bcd6/1) with the ids corrected in your table (since a bunch of them were 15). This returns record 18, for `2013-03-28`.

#### Update

After seeing the *correct* SQL fiddle... To incorporate the results of this query into your existing one, you can `LEFT JOIN` against it as a subquery on `p.id`.

```
select p.name,
  v.v_name,
  sum(case when Month(py.pay_date) = 4 then py.amount end) april_amount,

   (case when max(py.pay_date)and month(py.pay_date)= 4 then py.amount else 0 end) max_pay_april,

   sum(case 
        when Month(py.pay_date) = Month(curdate())
        then py.amount end) current_month_amount,
   sum(case 
        when Month(py.pay_date) = Month(curdate())-1
        then py.amount end) previous_month_amount,
   maxp.pay_date AS last_pay_date,
   maxp.amount AS last_pay_amount
from persons p
left join vehicle v
  on p.id = v.person_veh
left join payment py
  on p.id = py.person_id
/* LEFT JOIN against the subquery: */
left join (
   SELECT MAX(pay_date) AS pay_date, amount, person_id 
      FROM payment 
      WHERE pay_date BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND DATE_ADD('2012-03-31', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
      GROUP BY person_id, amount
    ) maxp ON maxp.person_id = p.id

group by p.name,
  v.v_name
```

Comment: WOW, so ..how do I include this with the other queries?

Comment: Plug this into your sqlfiddle. It returns record 15, March 28 2013. Why would you expect the result to be record 12 if you want dates between Apr 1 and March 31 next year?

Comment: @dames and how do you include into _what_ other queries?

Comment: O seems as if we were looking at two different fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb8e3/5)

Comment: @dames So you're trying to incorporate the pay_date into that fiddle's query?

Comment: yes sir, I am trying to add the answer you got to the queries I already have thats the reason I was using several cases

Comment: Don't mean to be annoying but where is the amount? Please

Comment: @dames Amount was omitted. I added it, but that means all your other references to `amount` need to be specified as `py.amount` to avoid ambiguity. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb8e3/22